# childnode of li element gives [#text, <ul>​…​</ul>​, #text]

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here I create a chat conversation.

The child nodes of the li element with `id="topOfStack"` i.e.

```
document.querySelector('#topOfStack').childNodes
```

results with:

```
[#text, <ul>​…​</ul>​, #text]
```

The HTML code for the my problem is below

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="chat">
        <li class="right">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Hello</span></li>
                <li><span> What are you doing?</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="left" id="topOfStack">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Watching Movie</span></li>
                <li><span>u?</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

But when I dynamically create a new "li" element and append to the chat(ul element) with id="topOfStack removed from the previous one and added to the newly appended element, the child nodes are only `[<ul>​…​</ul>​]`.

Why are #text added by default? or what role do they play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you see the spaces from the opening `<ul>` back to the beginning of the line? That's all text. The parser cannot know that those whitespaces are not significant (to you) and therefore creates a text node for them.

```
<li class="left" id="topOfStack"> |< line break here
    <ul>
^^^^
spaces here
```

When you dynamically create the elements, there is nothing to parse. You just directly add an element node to another one.

Answer (score 5):

Those text nodes represent text to the left and right of your `ul` tags. They're supposed to be there to signify that text. When you dynamically create an `<li>` tag with just a `<ul>` tag in it, that text isn't there. You could use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` to get just the elements:

```
document.querySelector('#topOfStack').children; //HTMLCollection: [<ul>...</ul>]
```

Comment: `element.children` [is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children#Browser_compatibility) by IE, even old versions.

Comment: It says it has basic support on `Element`, but not on `Document`. Same thing with Safari.

Comment: That does not matter. `.children` is only intersting for `Element` nodes.  A document only has one child node, namely the root. `document.children` is equivalent to `[document.documentElement]`.

Comment: Hm...I remember a StackOverflow question where a program didn't work on IE and Safari because of `.children`, though...Oh, well. I guess I must've misunderstood the accepted answer.